# How to convert a list of tuples of floats to list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples as follows -

```
my_list = [(0, nan), (20.307, 0.14045), (-16.879, 0.09363), (4.598, 0.06323)]
```

This list is a result of -

```
my_list = list(zip(list_a,list_b))
```

where `list_b` was created by appending the variances calculated from a series, hence the `nan`.

The expected output is -

```
my_list = ['0, nan','20.307, 0.14045', '-16.879, 0.09363', '4.598, 0.06323']
```

I tried looping through `my_list` but I am getting the error - `NameError: name 'nan' is not defined`

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: From your comments to one of the answers  - your data come as list, then you convert to pandas.Series, then you calculate var. provide full [mre]

Answer (score 1):

[`float("nan")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) is how python represents `NaN`.

you could do just this:

```
my_list = [(0, float("nan")), (20.307, 0.14045), (-16.879, 0.09363), (4.598, 0.06323)]

ret = [', '.join(str(i) for i in items) for items in my_list]
# ['0, nan', '20.307, 0.14045', '-16.879, 0.09363', '4.598, 0.06323']
```

or if there are always just two items in your list you could use an f-string:

```
ret = [f'{a}, {b}' for a, b in my_list]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The thing is, i can't change the list of tuples. Therefore, `float("nan")` is something that i can't really do.

Comment: in what form do you get the list of tuples then? as strings? (or did someone define `nan = float("nan")` somwehere in the code?)

Comment: The `nan` is coming from `my_series = pd.Series(list_x)`,`my_list.append(my_series.var().round(5))`.

Comment: this information is incomplete... why don't you ask a new question where you add the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you really want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [(0, None), (20.307, 0.14045), (-16.879, 0.09363), (4.598, 0.06323)]

result = [f'{x[0]},{x[1]}' for x in my_list]
```

you can do it with this
for each tuple in list add a string that consist first item and second item

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but let me answer to the best of my abilities. In any case, first thing you may need to do is:

```
from math import nan
```

to allow usage of `nan` literal.
If you want to convert `my_list` to strings, there is a oneliner that can do it:

```
my_list_strings = [", ".join(map(str, one_tuple)) for one_tuple in my_list]
```

Or, did you want `my_list` to be list of strings in the first place? One way to achieve that:

```
my_list = []
for single_str in zip(list_a, list_b):
    my_list.append(str(single_str[0]) + ", " + str(single_str[1]))
```